# ngx-intl-tel-input dropdown not closing after country selection with angular 13

Tags: popup, angular13, intl, intl-tel-input

Have ngx-intl-tel-input inside a popup, but after selecting the country the popup doesn't close.

Below is the form with ngx-intl-tel-input for the phone number input field.

```html
<form [formGroup]="assignForm">
              <input
                class="assignField"
                type="text"
                (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                (focus)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                formControlName="FirstName"
                placeholder="First Name"
              />
              <input
                class="assignField"
                type="text"
                (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                (focus)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                formControlName="LastName"
                placeholder="Last Name"
              />
              <input
                class="assignField"
                type="text"
                (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                (focus)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                formControlName="Email"
                placeholder="Email"
              />
              <div class="phoneInput-wrapper">
                <ngx-intl-tel-input   [cssClass]="'custom'"
                [enableAutoCountrySelect]="true" 
                [enablePlaceholder]="false" 
                [searchCountryFlag]="true" 
                [searchCountryField]="[
                        SearchCountryField.Iso2,
                        SearchCountryField.Name 
                      ]" 
                formControlName="Phone"
                [selectFirstCountry]="false"
                [selectedCountryISO]="country" 
                [maxLength]="15" 
                [phoneValidation]="true"
                [separateDialCode]="false" 
                [numberFormat]="PhoneNumberFormat.National" 
                name="Phone"
                (countryChange)="getCountry($event)">
              </ngx-intl-tel-input>
              </div>
            </form>
```

[image: the popup]

[image: the dropdown]

If I click on any country it the dropdown doesn't close.